# laravel and its file paths?what's wrong

Tags: laravel

just installed laravel, set the path to the file, but shouldn't the url change?.or am I writing something wrong?)

[image]

Comment: You must create virtual host to hit in url or `php artisan serve` to run the project

Answer (score 0):

Your root should be `/public` directly.

If you juste want to use it in development, I recommand using Valet if you are on mac (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet) Or homestead if you are on windows ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead)

Comment: if I register just localhost / public
I am told that there is no such file)

Comment: maybe it's worth creating a virtual host as suggested above?

Comment: can you please give us more information in your question : 
The environnement your are using (ex: Wamp, local server etc...)
The configuration file you are using setting the path, (or the screeshot of your configuration screen if using wamp)

Comment: ubuntu 18.04.Lamp-localserv

Comment: The configuration file-default

Comment: then you have to edit your file to point to `site/blog/public`

Comment: what should i edit
?
Route::get('/site/blog/public/'
I get an error

Comment: you have to edit your Lamp vhost configuration configuration file : 

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf, you have to replace this line : 

`DocumentRoot "~/site/blog/public"`  or whatever is the full path of your blog, then restart apache

Comment: look...
000-default.conf
default-ssl.conf

which one to edit?
I have them 2

Comment: should be your 000-default.conf

Comment: I'm already so tired of fixing it ... what should I see as a result, what will I have to enter, so that everything will work?))

Comment: Well it's level 0 of php programming so... If you don't want to have the hassle of configuring you environnement on your machine, you should use homestead in virtual box, just follow this tutorial : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead, you will be up and running in no time.

But you should definitely take some time to learn how your environnement works (You are working on Ubuntu so I assume you are willing to learn :) ), here is a basic tutorial on how it's works : https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/

Comment: Well .... so I created a virtual host, and why does it not start?)) I’m already added to host ip 127.0.0.1 — local, but he doesn’t want to connect